# Owns, owned, had owned, anyone would think

Tags: modal-verbs

Are the following sentences correct?

a) Anyone would think he ***owns/owned*** the place, from the way he ***talks***! (talking about the present)

b) Anyone would think he ***owned/had owned*** the place, from the way he ***talked***! (talking about the past)

c) Anyone **would've thought** he ***owned*** the place, from the way he ***talked***! (talking about the past)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I** In the first sentence "owned" is right. This second form is a past subjunctive and it is justified as the action of the verb (own) is counterfactual ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Use_of_the_past_subjunctive)).

> The past subjunctive form may be used similarly to express counterfactual conditions after suppose, as if, as though, unless, imagine etc.
>
> Suppose that I were there now.
> She looks as though she were going to kill him.
> Try to imagine he were here.
> Try to imagine a tool that made that easy for citizens.

It is possible though that in everyday speech people use the indicative present (owns).

> [ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=kWyL1cLf2bgC&pg=PA256&lpg=PA256&dq=everyday+speech,+indicative+present+or+past++subjunctive&source=bl&ots=KUZxVSWQfG&sig=ACfU3U2RTkXPuYXDPLoKhEzbEbJHx5e0nA&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiMnumP3dToAhUEA2MBHUQUAacQ6AEwC3oECGUQRQ#v=onepage&q=everyday%20speech%2C%20indicative%20present%20or%20past%20%20subjunctive&f=false)  The second condition under which the subjunctive should be used, when a situation contrary to fact or to reality is being hypothesyzed, seems to be slowly phasing out of Everyday speech.

This practice is not found in the written language ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=would+think+he+owns+the%2Cwould+think+he+owned+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwould%20think%20he%20owned%20the%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwould%20think%20he%20owned%20the%3B%2Cc0)).

**II** In the second sentence both subjunctive tenses express different contexts. The past subjunctive does not allow to assume more than an ownership before and  during  the time of talking (he talked). "Had owned" allows only to assume that ownership was asserted for only a time before the act of talking (he talked) ([past perfect subjunctive](https://www.grammaring.com/past-perfect-subjunctive)).

**III** In the third sentence, the verbs are also correct but instead of referring to people being asked their opinion any time, as in the preceding sentences (would think), you refer to people in the past only (would have thought).

Comment: A great explanation with references. In sentence b), isn't "owned" the indicative past form and "had owned" the subjunctive form?

Comment: @RizanMalik I believe that "owned" in that sentence is not the indicative, and that is so  (again as I see it) because this verb is introduced by "think". I think I can perceive what you seem to think: the person in question might really own the place and the sentence would be the expression of the fact that people would be induced to think so (there would be then no contrafactual condition). It seems to me that this new situation should be expressed differently: for instance "People would not fail to understand that he owned the place…", in which we do have to contend with a past indicative.